# Não retorna a quantidade de registros do banco de dados PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Gostaria de saber a quantidade de registros do meu banco de dados, mas não retorna a quantidade.

Olha os registros no meu banco de dados

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comando SQL

```
Select count(*) as contaRegistros from tb_produtos where prod_nome like '%"+  +"%';
```

Resultado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O seu where ta meio errado, qual sua intenção com ele?

Comment: quero pesquisar a quantidade de acordo com o nome , no caso o resultado desse select que coloquei era pra retornar todos os registros já que o campo de pesquisa esta vazia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta fazer desta forma:

```
Select count(*) as contaRegistros from tb_produtos;
```

Não esta funcionando por causa do seu where:

```
where prod_nome like '%"+  +"%';
```

Você deve ter copiado ele de algum trecho de código de forma errada.

Se precisar pesquisar algum valor, faça desta forma, vamos supor que o valor pesquisado é 'teste':

```
Select count(*) as contaRegistros from tb_produtos where prod_nome like '%teste%';
```

Comment: mas então Wictor e se futuramente quero pesquisar a quantidade de acordo com  o nome , no caso o resultado desse select que coloquei era pra retornar todos os registros já que o campo de pesquisa esta vazia

Comment: Ai você tem que colocar assim where prod_nome like '%%'; ai ele vai buscar tudo e se for fazer alguma pesquisa where prod_nome like '%valor%'; claro que isso vai depender da linguagem que você esta utilizando, se estiver utilizando só no bando direto desta forma vai funcionar.

Comment: coloquei o comando que vc falou mas não retornou todos os registros Select count(*) as contaRegistros from tb_produtos where prod_nome like '%" "%';

Comment: você tem que fazer sem as "": Select count(*) as contaRegistros from tb_produtos where prod_nome like '%%';

Comment: Se você colocar as "" ele vai pesquisar valores que tem "".

Comment: e se eu quisesse  colocar esse comando em java por exemplo como seria ?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67904/discussion-between-wictor-chaves-and-user1999).